# Efficient way to replace an element in a list of tuples by performing look up from another list (python)

Tags: python

I have a list of tuples, like so:

```
tuple_list = [(id-1,value-1),(id-2,value-2),....(id-n,value-n)]
```

Likewise, I have a list of objects that relates to the `ids` in the list above, i.e.:

```
object_list = [<obj-3>,<obj-1>,....<obj-n>]
```

Note that the order in `object_list` is different.

I'd like to generate a new list which is exactly like the first one above, except instead of `id`, it should have the object itself in it.I.e.

```
resulting_list = [(<obj-1>,value-1),(<obj-2>,value-2),...(<obj-n>,value-n)]
```

What would be the most efficient way to perform this?

---

I'm trying it inside two for loops currently:

```
resulting_list = []
for tpl in tuple_list:
    for obj in object_list:
        if tpl[0] == obj.id
        resulting_list.append((obj,tpl[1]))
```

Comment: Is every id in `tuple_list` guaranteed to have a matching object in `object_list`?

Comment: @PM2Ring: yes, guaranteed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Construct a `dict` where keys are are object ids and values are objects. Then iterate over `tuple_list` within list comprehension and for each tuple output object from `dict` and value from original list:

```
class Obj:
    def __init__(self, id):
        self.id = id

    def __repr__(self):
        return 'Obj({})'.format(self.id)

tuple_list = [(0, 'Zero'), (1, 'One'), (2, 'Two'), (3, 'Three'), (4, 'Four')]
object_list = [Obj(i) for i in range(4, -1, -1)]

d = {o.id: o for o in object_list}
result = [(d[_id], val) for _id, val in tuple_list]

print(result)
```

Output:

```
[(Obj(0), 'Zero'), (Obj(1), 'One'), (Obj(2), 'Two'), (Obj(3), 'Three'), (Obj(4), 'Four')]
```

Time complexity of above is **O(n)** where as original code with nested loops is **O(n^2)**.

Comment: @MarcusMüller Yes, it does. But we aren't given an iterable of (key, value) tuples here.

Comment: isn't it `(hashable, value)`?

Answer (score 1):

If your lists have length `n` then your current algorithm does `n` iterations on the outer loop, and `n` iterations on each inner loop, giving a total of `n*n`. You could improve that by breaking out of the inner loop as soon as you find a match. That will give an average of `n*n/2`.

But it's better to do two loops each of length `n`, since for large `n` `2n` is much smaller than `n*n`. In the code below, the first loop constructs a dictionary with the object id as the key and the object itself as the value. Then the second loop can quickly find the object from its id.

```
obj_map = {obj.id: obj for obj in object_list}
resulting_list = [(obj_map[k], v) for k, v in tuple_list]
```

---

If it's possible that some ids in `tuple_list` don't have a matching object in `obj_map` and you don't want to fail with a `KeyError` in that situation you can do

```
resulting_list = [(obj_map.get(k), v) for k, v in tuple_list]
```

which will supply `None` for any missing objects.

Alternatively,

```
resulting_list = [(obj_map.get(k, default_object), v) for k, v in tuple_list]
```

which will supply `default_object` for missing objects.

Answer (score 0):

```
...
    i = object_list.index(tpl[0]) if tpl[0] in tuple_list else -1
    if i > -1:
      resulting_list.append((object_list[i],tpl[1]))
```